# Regular Exp. in Eclipse, Find and Replace: Match everything between curly braces

Tags: regex, eclipse

I would like to match everything between and including curly braces in eclipse find and replace (it can be assumed that there are no inner curly braces but any other character including all types of whitespace.

```
int SomeMethodName() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   return asdfasdf.rearoiula12123893;
}
```

Right now I am trying this and it only matches curly braces with nothing in them `\{[.\s]*\}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `.` inside a character class means a `.` literal, not a wildcard. You need something more like:

```
\{.*?\}
```

Depending on how Eclipse treats new line characters you might need to change it to:

```
\{(.|\r\n?|\n)*?\}
```

Comment: Try taking his second solution but move the asterix outside the grouping. In other words, try using this instead: `\{(.|\r\n?|\n)*\}`

Comment: It matches greedly then (as does the attempt by Aaron below), I need it to match the smallest possible match

Comment: @tjb, sorry, I fixed it. (Non Greedy)

Comment: Sorry, I should have realized that. Add a question mark after the asterix. That will cause the engine to use lazy matching instead of greedy matching. `\{(.|\r\n?|\n)*?\}`

Comment: Regular expressions are vicious, the second one works, thanks for your help, I have, of course, already done the job by hand as I was waiting for answers :), but it will come in handy next time

Comment: Why not simply `\{[^\}]*\}`? Select open brace, then all characters other than closing brace, then closing brace.

Answer (score 4):

This should work.  Tested using Regex Powertoy [here](http://regex.powertoy.org/).

`\{[\s\W\w]*\}`

EDIT:

`\{[\s\w\. /=(":);]*\}` should stop at the nearest closing brace.  The piece after the space has all the miscellaneous non-word characters, so you might have to add to that depending on the nature of what you're parsing (e.x. a weird String).

Comment: almost, but it matches more then what I need, I need to match one opening brace and the immediate closing brace, this skips several braces (i.e. matches the first brace behind the cursor and the last brace in the file)

Comment: Edited my answer above.  The closing brace is included in the non-word character class (\W), so the non-word characters need to be inserted manually (e.x. ;.\/-+=).

Comment: Props for mentioning that regex testing tool.